# Cursor missing in table view of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, editing, arcgis-10.4

In QGIS attribute tables there is a blinking cursor when editing data in tables. This is a very helpful feature that makes the orientation esp. in longer attribute values quite easy, or even just possible as well:

[image]

In ArcGIS 10.4 I miss such cursor (not necessarily blinking...), and it is mostly impossible for me (apart from counting the cursor-left-keystrokes) to predict where a character is going to appear:

[image]

I must miss some settings (table appearance, font-size?).

Comment: Yay! I got a cursor in ArcGIS - and it's blinking!!! Not that I don't do most of my edits in QGIS, but from time to time... ;-)

Comment: I was wondering when you became a traitor to QGIS ;)

Comment: Never. And never will. But sometimes your employer demands things from you that you're not proud on. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESRI has acknowledged this problem and has provided a solution/workaround. The following is simply quoted from ESRI Support:

[Problem: When editing attribute tables, the cursor disappears or is not visible](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008578)

---

> ## Cause
>
> One cause of this problem is the monitor resolution setting. When it is set to Large size (120 DPI), the cursor or insert point when editing attribute tables may not be visible.
>
> Another cause is that the table's appearance, specifically the table font, font size, column header height and/or cell height has been modified, causing the cursor to not be visible.

---

> ## Solution or Workaround
>
> Reset the monitor display resolution to Normal size (96dpi) and/or reset the attribute table appearance settings.
>
> ---
>
> - Reset monitor display:
>
>   1. Right-click anywhere on the Windows desktop and select Properties.
>   2. Click the Settings tab, and click the Advanced button. This opens the graphics card driver properties dialog box.
>   3. On the General tab, look at the DPI setting. If it is set to 'Large size (120 DPI)', click the drop-down menu and select 'Normal size (96 DPI)'. Click OK and follow the instructions, if necessary, to install.
>   4. Reboot the computer.
>
> ---
>
> - Reset the attribute table appearance settings:
>
>   1. In an existing map document, click Options > Appearance on the Attributes dialog box. To reset the appearance settings for all new map documents, navigate to Options and click the Tables tab.
>   2. Reset the Appearance settings so that font, font size, column header height and cell height accommodate the cursor. The default settings are:
>        Table Font: MS Sans Serif
>        Table Font Size: 8
>        Column Header Height: 125%
>        Cell Height: 115%